# Pop up the Kendo Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have pop up the Kendo Window.
But it pops up only on first time.

And after closing the window it doesn't works again.

```
$("#open1").click(function() {
    $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "100px",
        modal: true,
        title: "Window 1"
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/nt2XX/275/)

Here is the window pop up which I have done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `visible: false` from [docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window) like,

```
$("#win1").kendoWindow({
    width: "300px",
    height: "100px",
    modal: true,
    title: "Window 1",
    visible: false
});
$("#open1").click(function () {
    $("#win1").data("kendoWindow").open();
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnuE3/)